# why my multi-output regression using pytorch only optimize one output?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, linear-regression

I want to predict three outputs, the model is as follows. the features of input is 9, output is 3.

```
class DNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_features):
        self.n_features = n_features
        super(DNN, self).__init__()
        self.inlayer1 = nn.Linear(self.n_features, 16)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(16, 32)
        self.layer3 = nn.Linear(32, 64)
        self.layer4 = nn.Linear(64, 128)
        self.layer5 = nn.Linear(128, 256)
        self.layer6 = nn.Linear(256, 256)
        self.layer7 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
        self.layer8 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.layer9 = nn.Linear(64, 32)
        self.layer10 = nn.Linear(32, 16)
        self.outlayer = nn.Linear(16, 3)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.elu(self.inlayer1(x))
        x = F.elu(self.layer2(x))
        x = F.elu(self.layer3(x))
        x = F.elu(self.layer4(x))
        x = F.elu(self.layer5(x))
        x = F.elu(self.layer6(x))
        x = F.elu(self.layer7(x))
        x = F.elu(self.layer8(x))
        x = F.elu(self.layer9(x))
        x = F.elu(self.layer10(x))
        out = self.outlayer(x)
        return out
```

The train code

```
def train(net, train_features, train_labels, test_features, test_labels,
          num_epochs, learning_rate, weight_decay, batch_size):
    train_ls, test_ls = [], []
    train_iter = d2l.load_array((train_features, train_labels), batch_size)
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(),
                                 lr = learning_rate,
                                 weight_decay = weight_decay)
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for X, y in train_iter:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            out = net(X)     ##out.shape is (100 samples, 3 labels)
            loss = MSEloss(out, y)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        train_ls.append(MSEloss(net(train_features), train_labels).item())
        if test_labels is not None:
            test_ls.append(MSEloss(net(test_features), test_labels).item())
    return train_ls, test_ls
```

after running the model, the below result is incorrect, but i don't know where is the bug? It seems that only the first col label is right. Should i change my method of calculating loss?
the below is the result.
[the R2 and MSE metrics for three outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru1C3.png)

I tried to calculate the three outputs(out1, out2, out3) separately by change the number of output neurons to 1, then calculate the weighted loss, but it didn't work, even all three outputs are not close to the real label.

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't give us enough information to be really helpful.  What is your learning rate? What about weight decay? If weight decay is too high it can cause this issue.  Probably best to turn it off for debugging. Finally is it even possible to learn the 3 outputs from the input? Can you do it yourself from the data?

Comment: `num_epochs, lr, weight_decay, batch_size = 500, 0.001, 0, 32`, I used the default weight_decay=0. Firstly I used the TF's model.fit() method to learn the outputs, had a R2=[0.82, 0.62, 0.72], but when I use the pytorch model with the same parameters comparing to TF, it doesn't works. The TF parameters is as follows: `model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss = tf.keras.losses.mse, metrics = tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError())`  `model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, epochs=2000, validation_data=(xTest, yTest))`

Comment: It's weird to compare things when they aren't the same.  You're comparing TF code with different parameters to pytorch code.  2000 epochs vs 500 epochs, whats the batch size in TF?   I'm sorry there's still quite a bit missing from the code above. How are you evaluating the model in pytorch?